# Nav menu in footer cut off (opens vertically)

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to make my footer menu open upwards, but the menu is getting cut off at the top of the footer. I've tried setting `overflow-y:visible;`, but that doesn't help.

Here's the site: http://new.freshsourdoughexpress.com/contact/

And the code I'm using:

```
#colophon {
    padding-top: 40px;
    overflow-y: visible;
}

#colophon #navbar ul li:hover ul {
    bottom:100%;
    top:auto;
}
#colophon #navbar ul ul li:hover ul {
    bottom:0;
}
```

(The top padding is temporary, just to see what's happening.)

I've been following the 3rd how-to in this guide: http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/move-wordpress-theme-menus/

How do I get the menu to extend out of the footer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your `CSS`, you'll need to add a couple of attributes to the id below.

```
#colophon {
    padding-top: 40px;
    overflow: visible;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I've tried it out using the `CSS` editor within Chrome and everything seems to work.